# Prioritized joining of PySpark dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say I have two PySpark dataframes.

```
df1
| A     | B              |
| ----- | -------------- |
| foo   | B1             |
| bar   | B2             |
| baz   | B3             |
| lol   | B9            |

df2
| X      | Y  | Z       |
| ------ | -- | --------|
| bar    | B1 | Cool    |
| foo    | B2 | Awesome |
| val    | B3 | Superb  |
| bar    | B4 | Nice    |
```

How do I join these dataframes to `df3` so that I

1. prioritize joining `df1["A"]` with `df2["X"]` and get the values from `df2["Z"]`,
   and
2. if any of the `df3["Z"]` values are `null`, fill in the `null` values
   with the values that would have been the result from joining `df1["B"]` with `df2["Y"]` and getting the values from `df2["Z"]`?

Examplified I want to end up with `df4` rather than `df3` (note the `null` value in df3):

```
df3
| A   | B  | Z       |
| --- | -- | ------- |
| foo | B1 | Awesome |
| bar | B2 | Cool    |
| bar | B4 | Nice    |
| baz | B3 | null    |
| lol | B9 | null    |

df4
| A   | B  | Z       |
| --- | -- | ------- |
| foo | B1 | Awesome |
| bar | B2 | Cool    |
| bar | B4 | Nice    |
| baz | B3 | Superb  |
| lol | B9 | null    |
```

My non-simplified real-world example has many duplicates, a lot of columns etc. so I can't see if a simple when/otherwise statement will be sufficient (or perhaps I am just completely lost...). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing two joins:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df4 = df1.join(
    df2,
    df1['A'] == df2['X'],
    'left'
).select(
    'A', 'B', 'Z'
).alias('df3').join(
    df2.alias('df2'),
    F.expr('df3.B = df2.Y and df3.Z is null'),
    'left'
).select(
    'A', 'B', F.coalesce('df3.z', 'df2.z').alias('z')
)

df4.show()
+---+---+-------+
|  A|  B|      z|
+---+---+-------+
|foo| B1|Awesome|
|bar| B2|   Nice|
|bar| B2|   Cool|
|baz| B3| Superb|
|lol| B9|   null|
+---+---+-------+
```

Or if you prefer 1 join only,

```
df4 = df1.join(
    df2,
    (df1['A'] == df2['X']) | (df1['B'] == df2['Y']), 
    'left'
).selectExpr(
    '*',
    'max(A = X) over(partition by A, B) as flag'
).filter(
    '(flag and A = X) or not flag or flag is null'
).select(
    'A','B','Z'
)

df4.show()
+---+---+-------+
|  A|  B|      Z|
+---+---+-------+
|bar| B2|   Cool|
|bar| B2|   Nice|
|foo| B1|Awesome|
|lol| B9|   null|
|baz| B3| Superb|
+---+---+-------+
```